# How to prove $cn < n^{\log_{2}n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How do you prove that for any given $c$, there exists an $n$ such that $$cn < n^{\log_{2}n}$$ ? I know that I have to write $n$ in terms of $c$, but I'm having trouble with the log in the exponent.

Comment: If $c\rightarrow+\infty$ the left hand side is infinity but the right hand side is just a fixed finite number.

Comment: Maybe you mean to write: for any given (but fixed!) $c$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$, we have the inequality.

Comment: Yes! That's what I meant, thank you

Comment: @sesameseedball:  being careful with things like that is a big step in doing math. When you write the question carefully it often pushes you toward the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As updated in Clayton's comment, just require that $n \gt 4$, then the log is greater than $2$, and say $n^{\log_2 n} \gt n^2$.  Now use your argument that eventually $n^2 \gt cn$.  This will not necesarily find you the minimum $n$ that works, but you were not asked for that.

Comment: thank you :) the answer was simpler than I thought

Answer (score 0):

I think choice of n has to depend on c otherwise we can always contradict it by choosing a c higher than $n^{log_2 n}/n$.

$nc<n^{log_en/log_e2}$ $\implies$ $nc<n^{(ln(n))^2/(ln(n)ln(2))}$ $\implies$ $nc<n^{(log_nn) (ln(n)/ln(2))}$ $\implies$ $nc<nn^{ln(n)/ln(2)}$ $\implies$$c<n^{ln(n)/ln(2)}$ $\implies$ $c^{ln(2)}<n^{ln(n)}$
taking log on both sides $ln(2)ln(c)<(ln(n))^2$ $\implies$ $(ln(2)ln(c))^{1/2}<(ln(n))$ So $n>e^{(ln(2)ln(c))^{1/2}}$

Here $ln(x)=log_ex$

Comment: You are correct that the choice of $n$ has to depend on $c$.  The correct problem statement has $c$ chosen first and then we need to show there is such an $n$.